# why does my vscode report error, but the code can be compiled by cmake

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-code

I have installed the opencv package using `brew install opencv`, the installation is successful. 
Then I download the example code from [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/samples/cpp/example_cmake).
I can compile it successfully using `cmake`. And I can also run it.
However, my vscode editor seems it can not located the header file of cpp, thus it shows these error. The screenshot is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiChq.png).
How can I fix this problem? 
Thank you!

Comment: do you have an `cpp_options.json` file?

Comment: Thank you, I sort it out myself, I set the path in the software.